# Why I am not able to run Internet explore oriented sites on ubuntu?

Tags: wine, playonlinux

I am ubuntu user from 2 months and actually i want to visit the bulhorn.com website and this bullhorn.com portal is only suitable with Internet explorer.

In order to visit bullhorn.com site I have installed PlayonLinux tool to install IE 8 on my ubuntu system.

But IE 8 is not so good.It takes 15 mins to open any site.

I have searched lots on google but I am not getting that how I can use IE oriented sites on my ubuntu.

Please suggest me efficient way to visit IE oriented websites on ubuntu.

Comment: I dont why Bullhorn is suitable with IE.If I would know that Why I will post the question here

Comment: Tried again in IE 10. Now it works, User agent switcher is the way to go.

Comment: Bullhorn have a post on their site where they argue with other customers why IE is a better browser than the rest. http://www.bullhorn.com/blog/index.php/2011/04/when-will-bullhorn-work-on-browsers-other-than-internet-explorer

they are just lazy. IE never follows any internet standards and  therefor you need two write more code to make them work for everything...

Comment: As of 2016, bullhorn is fine in Chrome and Firefox

Answer (score 5):

Your first step should be to complain.

I'm shocked there are still businesses pushing things that require a set browser. It's reflective of a development process that went out the window over a decade ago. This is their active choice. That's the why.

You can usually work around simple blocks with [User Agent Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/). I've used it for some banking in the past. Firefox will just "pretend" to be IE and this is enough to get past most issues.

You might find that some things don't work. They might be coded so single-mindedly for IE that Firefox just refuses to continue... Or they might be doing capability-based testing to work out if you're using IE (which User Agent Switcher won't cover). If that's the case, your only good option is virtualising.

And by that I mean installing VirtualBox or VMWare Workstation, and installing Windows inside that. You'll then be able to run a real copy of WIndows and a real copy of Internet Explorer within your Ubuntu session. This obviously nukes a portion of disk space and takes time to boot but it's feature complete. You're not running into winegecko issues every other pageload.